# How can I have multiple content types pick up the same template?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I want to override the template for 5 content type that they have all the same attributes, but a different name ,so the suggestion  is :

```
node--contenttype1.html.twig 
node--contenttype2.html.twig 
node--contenttype3.html.twig 
node--contenttype4.html.twig 
node--contenttype5.html.twig
```

how can i implement a same override for all those 5 content type ?

Comment: See docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions#s-nodes - use `node.html.twig`

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd simply use `node.html.twig` and then have different node templates for other node types. But I can imagine that it can make sense to bundle certain node types differently instead of providing distinctive templates for all other node types.

So you can implement [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) or [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) to provide an extra template suggestion. The following snippet lets nodes of a given type pick up a `node--foobar.html.twig` template if present.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $bundles = [
    'contenttype1',
    'contenttype2',
    'contenttype3',
    'contenttype4',
    'contenttype5',
  ];

  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];

  if (in_array($node->bundle(), $bundles)) {
    $suggestions[] = 'node__foobar';
    $suggestions[] = 'node__foobar__' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
  }
}
```